# Mock a method with parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am mocking my controller method and my controller looks like this

My controller:

```
public class PController : BaseController
{
    readonly IRFacade _repository;

    public PController()
    {
        _repository =  new RiFacade();
    }

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public PController(IRFacade repositories)
    {
        if (repositories == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("repositories");
        _repository = repositories;
    }

    public aMethod(String Id){
        int[] arraynum = convert id to int[]
        int numberthis = _repository.ActionFunction(arraynum);
        ..return stuff

    }
```

the interface `IRFacade` that i created look like this

```
public interface IRFacade 
{        
    int ActionFunction(int[] arrayOfNum);
}
```

when I test `aMethod` and I have to mock `_repository` I do it like this for the set up

```
var MockFacade = new Mock<IRFacade>();
// here fakeinput is a int[] varaible and aNumber is a int variable
MockFacade.Setup(r => r.ActionFunction(fakeinput)).Returns(aNumber);
```

My question is that why do I have to pass an actual int[] varaible `fakeInput` that I declared as oppose to just passing in a argument type `r.ActionFunction(int[] avaraible)` when I am setting up the Mock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you setup your method like this:

```
MockFacade.Setup(r => r.ActionFunction(new[] {1,2,3})).Returns(5);
```

You're setting it up to return 5 *if*, and only *if*, an array with the numbers 1, 2 and 3 was passed as an argument.

If you want your method to return 5 for *any* input, you should use `It.IsAny<T>()` instead.

```
MockFacade.Setup(r => r.ActionFunction(It.IsAny<int[]>())).Returns(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you want an `array` of 1,2,3

```
MockFacade.Setup(r => r.ActionFunction(new int[]{1,2,3})).Returns(aNumber);
```

If you want any `int` `array`:

```
MockFacade.Setup(r => r.ActionFunction(It.IsAny<int[]>())).Returns(aNumber);
```

If you want to make sure your `array` has 1 at least, but you can always build on more conditions through `lambda`:

```
MockFacade.Setup(r => r.ActionFunction(It.Is<int[]>(a=>a.Contains(1)))).Returns(aNumber);
```